# Section expert in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report having a section.Now i want to know whether the section got suppressed or not based on the logic i gave.

I just want show a message true when the section is suppressed false when it is not suppressed.
Please suggest how to do

Comment: Hey vissubabu, why you want to show true or false? you can even add any column in the section and see on the report if it is suppressed or not. Is there a requirement to show true or false? or you just want to check whether it is suppressed?

Comment: Hi Pratik,  it is a requirement from the client.Please suggest how to do

Comment: What about adding another section? will it help? Position of columns will be different in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of suppress formula in section, add supress condition on each column present in the section. Then add one more formula in the same section which will print "true" or "false" based on your provided conditional logic. To that formula add suppress condition with logic exactly opposite to other columns suppress condition logic. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pratik is right in that you can't suppress a whole section and then have a true or false show up in it. Depending on how many sections (groups) you have, you can put your true/false logik in the group header (if you don't have one, create one) and then suppress the detail section which has your columns in it. That would be a little less work then having to suppress every field in the section.

Hope that helps,

Chris